# first ajax request extremely slow in Firefox but fast in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a simple jQuery Ajax request to which the server replies with a static, empty JSON array (to rule out any DB performance issues). The request is called on `.change` of a `select` field; the result is used to highlight/disable some of the `select` field's entries.

```
$.post(url, $('#inputForm').serialize(), function(data) {//do something});
```

When the request is sent for the first time after a page refresh, it takes Firefox (19) multiple seconds---sometimes more than 10---to get a response (as seen in Firebug). Subsequent responses however are received within milliseconds. IE (9), somewhat surprisingly, immediately gets fast responses after page refreshes.

The behaviour is regardless of whether or not cache-control headers are being sent.

The issue has been brought up in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492730/jquery-ajax-function-call-is-slow-first-time) but not yet been answered.

Any ideas on what might slow down Firefox on the first request?

[image]

Comment: When are you calling your post?

Comment: show us your first request's content :D

Comment: it can be a network latency, can you expand you first request by clicking on plus icon?

Comment: @BradM it's on `.change` (added to question).

Comment: @Nazariy testing on localhost, accessing by IP. Since IE doesn't have the problem, this seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @dgs if you hover a bar for first request it would show a tooltip this detailed information like DNS Lookup, Connecting, Sending, Waiting, Receiving. Which operation takes more time to complete? My first guess it can be some of the firefox extensions.

Comment: @Nazariy it's all waiting time, everything else is zero seconds. Problem remains with all add-ons inactivated.

Comment: Try to benchmark performance of your server side script, with PHP it can be done by placing `$start = microtime(true);` before all processing starts and `echo microtime(true) - $start;` before sending response back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Changing localhost to 127.0.0.1, fixed my slow firefox ver26.0 slow ajax issue.